# BIRT Reporting with Date picker not working

Tags: javascript, datepicker, reporting, birt, jscalendar

I am using BIRT RCP 4.8. I am trying to add a date picker in Parameter Tab. I have modified FramesetFragment.jsp as below...

```
<script src="birt/JSCal2-1.9/src/js/jscal2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="birt/JSCal2-1.9/src/js/lang/en.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="birt/JSCal2-1.9/src/css/border-radius.css" meda="screen" type="text/css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="birt/JSCal2-1.9/src/css/jscal2.css" meda="screen" type="text/css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="birt/JSCal2-1.9/src/css/gold/gold.css" meda="screen" type="text/css"/>
```

And TextBoxParameterFragment.jsp as

```
    <INPUT TYPE="HIDDEN" ID="isRequired" 
            VALUE = "<%= parameterBean.isRequired( )? "true": "false" %>">
     <%
if (parameterBean.getParameter().getDataType()==7|| parameterBean.getParameter().getDataType()==4) {
%>

<button id="<%=parameterBean.getName()%>_button">...</button>
<script type="text/javascript">
    Calendar.setup({
        trigger    : '<%=parameterBean.getName()%>_button',
        inputField : '<%=parameterBean.getName()%>',
                onSelect   : function() { this.hide() }
    });
</script>


 <%
}
%>
```

But still i am getting no buttons for selecting date in WebViewer or after deployment. Gone through all the resource, any help is appreciated..
Reference Link 
[enter link description here](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/iotsupport/entry/Adding_a_calendar_date_picker_to_a_TRIRIGA_BIRT_report?lang=en)

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer for the above...The parameter which i created for getting the date from user was set to String type....And hence button was not getting displayed. I have changed the same in BIRT Report Designer and its working now...!!!!Aola...